# Create Bootstrap selector

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, testing, css-selectors, selector, testcafe

I try to create a Selector for Bootstrap buttons. The element I have is

```
<div class="cl-button-secoundary bc-managment-btn bc-managment-btn-delete cl-button-animated empty-trash-button" style="opacity: 0.2;">
    <span>Papierkorb leeren</span>
</div>
```

I try to create a query with selector not exists:

```
        if (await Selector('div.cl-button-secoundary').filter('.empty-trash-button').exists.notOk()) {
            await t
                .click(Selector('span').withText('Papierkorb leeren'))
                .click(Selector('.cl-button.cl-button.cl-button-animated'))
        }
```

I also tried

```
        if (await Selector('div').filter('.empty-trash-button').exists.notOk()) {
            await t
                .click(Selector('span').withText('Papierkorb leeren'))
                .click(Selector('.cl-button.cl-button.cl-button-animated'))
        }
```

I understand that way, that filter will look for a class? I have many Bootstrap elements that I can only differ with subclass. What I understood wrong?

Comment: If I understanding the selector correctly, you shouldn't need to put 'notOk()'.  Just by having .exists will return either true or false.  Just use that logic to determine.  Give that a try

Comment: Sorry, no change if I remove notOk(). It still ignore this element.

Comment: Can you sue 'find' versus 'filter'?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the approach suggested by @TallKU.

If you want to do something if a specific element exists, you need to write the following code:

```
if (await Selector('div.cl-button-secoundary').filter('.empty-trash-button').exists) {
    await t.click(Selector('span').withText('Papierkorb leeren'));
}
```

If you want to do something if the element does not exist, you need this:

```
if (!await Selector('div.cl-button-secoundary').filter('.empty-trash-button12345').exists) {
    console.log('the `empty-trash-button12345` element does not exist');
}
```